# Arial Font rendering differs in Chrome vs IE

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, fonts

The Arial font is rendered much lighter and thinner in Chrome compared to IE.

Is there a way to have Arial render the same in the popular browsers (IE8+ FF Chrome Safari)?

If I bought or downloaded a custom font, is it possible to have this custom font replace the browser's default Arial font?  And would it be consistent across the browsers for all users?

I have many style sheets referencing Arial, so I am unable to change each style tag to reference a new name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, different browsers have different font-rendering engines. There is literally no way to guarantee that the text will render identically. Even if you use `@font-face`, it will still render differently.

Comment: Is it possible to redefine Arial using @font-face? I know you can import new fonts and give them new names.  I need to keep the name as Arial.  If so, do you think by doing this it may make Chrome render a bit darker?

Comment: Yes. The browser will look at `@font-face` rules for the font name before looking at the user's computer.